# In Inno Setup, can I add a note (static text) to the Select Tasks page?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, can I add a note (static text) to the Select Tasks page?  For added bonus, I would like the note to be blue.

Comment: Sure you can, but where ? There's not much space left on the tasks page.

Comment: There is plenty of room on my tasks page, I only have three options.  I would like to put the note below the last option but above the buttons.

Comment: So it seems I was lucky this time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every page of the wizard form can be modified, including tasks page. Problem might be the space left on that page. In the following example I cut the `TasksList` bottom (as you didn't say where do you want to put your note) and into the gain space inserted a static text:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Tasks]
Name: task1; Description: "1. Task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: task2; Description: "2. Task"; Flags: unchecked

[Code]
const
  NoteHeight = 50;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Note: TNewStaticText;
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.Height := WizardForm.TasksList.Height - NoteHeight;

  Note := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  Note.Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
  Note.AutoSize := False;
  Note.SetBounds(
    WizardForm.TasksList.Left,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Top + WizardForm.TasksList.Height,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Width,
    NoteHeight
  );
  Note.Font.Color := clBlue;
  Note.Caption := 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing' + #13#10 +
    'elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
end;
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much TLama, for this question and others.  As a side note, this project appears to be nearing a close, thank goodness.  I have been working on it on and off for a while.  Not really my cup of tea, better at math and algorithms but someone had to do this.  Thanks for everything!