# Inno Setup - Conditionally hide/show static text based on task selection

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```pascal
[Components]
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"; Types: Slasher Full
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon Frankenstein"; Types: Frankenstein Full

[Types]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Dagon Video Tools"
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon FrankenStein"

[Tasks]
Name: "Debug"; Description: "Nothing"; Components: not Slasher
Name: "Vid"; Description: "Install Extra Codecs for Frankenstein"; Flags: unchecked; Components: not Slasher

[Code]
var
  Warning: TNewStaticText;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Warning := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  Warning.Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
  Warning.Visible := False;
  Warning.AutoSize := False;
  Warning.SetBounds(
    WizardForm.TasksList.Left,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Top + WizardForm.TasksList.Height,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Width,
    50
  );
  Warning.Font.Color := clRed;
  Warning.Caption := 'Warning: This will result in a non-functional "Join in FrankenStein" button in the Tools Menu.';
end;
```

I used yet another amazing piece of [code by TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26288237/3993104). The problem is I need the note to be visible when the user selects the task, and be hidden otherwise (while on the same page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle `WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck` event and update the `Warning` label visibility accordingly.

```pascal
var
  Warning: TNewStaticText;

procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Warning.Visible :=
    { This (and the task index below)  has to be kept in sync with the expression }
    { in "Components" parameter of the respective task. }
    { Though note that in your specific case the test }
    { is redundant as when "Slasher" is selected, you have no tasks, }
    { and the "Tasks" page is completely skipped, so you do not even get here. }
    (not IsComponentSelected('Slasher')) and
    WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[0]; { You can also use WizardIsTaskSelected }
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Warning := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ...
  { Update Warning label visibility on task selection change }
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    { Update initial visibility }
    TasksListClickCheck(WizardForm.TasksList);
  end;
end;
```

[image: Task selected]

[image: Task unselected]

---

Side notes:

- Do not hard code the height to fixed `50`. Scale it with DPI instead: `ScaleY(50)`.
- You should set `Warning.WordWrap := True` as the caption does not fit page width.
- You should shrink `TasksList`'s height as the label does not fit below the list. You are missing the `WizardForm.TasksList.Height := WizardForm.TasksList.Height - NoteHeight;` from @TLama's code. Again note that he is missing the scaling of the `NoteHeight`.

```pascal
const
  NoteHeight = 50;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.Height := WizardForm.TasksList.Height - ScaleY(NoteHeight);

  Warning := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  Warning.Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
  Warning.AutoSize := False;
  Warning.WordWrap := True;
  Warning.SetBounds(
    WizardForm.TasksList.Left,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Top + WizardForm.TasksList.Height,
    WizardForm.TasksList.Width,
    ScaleY(NoteHeight)
  );
  Warning.Font.Color := clRed;
  { Update Warning label visibility on task selection change }
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck
  Warning.Caption :=
    'Warning: This will result in a non-functional "Join in FrankenStein" button ' +
    'in the Tools Menu.';
end;
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. After the last edit, it works (the first one, obviously affected other component combinations, too)! It just seems so stupid that the solution is so easy and I get confused in all the numbers/combinations and stuff. I swear, the day I can do this all in my head, putting it into script will be a lot easier.